# Wrong WindowState when form is Minimized

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I have an issue when my `MainForm` isn't visible.

I reproduce it with a `TForm` and a `TTimer` (interval 5sec).
The timer method changes the location of the MainForm:

```
Timer.Enabled := False;    
Application.MainForm.Bounds := TRect.Create(0, 0, 200, 200);
```

If the form is minimized during the timer event, the location of the form doesn't change. I tried to change the `WindowState`, but when I log it, I have `wsNormal` instead of `wsMinimized`:

```
Timer.Enabled := False;    
 
if Application.MainForm.WindowState = wsMinimized then // never got wsMinimized
  Application.MainForm.WindowState = wsNormal;
    
Application.MainForm.Bounds := TRect.Create(0, 0, 200, 200);
```

The only solution I have found is to add this call in my timer event before changing the bounds:

```
ShowWindow(WindowHandleToPlatform(GetMainForm.Handle).Wnd, SW_RESTORE);
```

Why is `WindowState` showing as `wsNormal` instead of `wsMinimized`? What property can I check to know if my form is minimized or not?

Comment: i tryed Application.MainForm.Show will work like ShowWindow(WindowHandleToPlatform(GetMainForm.Handle).Wnd, SW_RESTORE);

Comment: *If the form is minimized...the location of the form don't change* Of course it doesn't, the form is minimized, so its location is a button on the taskbar and there's no position to change - that change wouldn't be seen, because the window is minimized. Windows will also not draw on forms that are minimized or not visible, because that drawing cannot be seen. Why would you expect otherwise? Set the window position when the form is being shown again.

Comment: So, why the state stay at `wsNormal` when the form is minimized with the window button ? it should check the Win API to avoid some errors

Answer (score 0):

1 - the windows state on FMX is equal to the last value written
and when you get the state you recive the last value written. the default value is wsNormal do not change when the form is minimized by the window minimize button (Readed the FMX Code and tested with breakpoint). is wrapped the SetWindowsState on FMX but not the UpdateWindowsState

2 - if you want to Get the state of you windows in windows
you need to:

- add uses FMX.Platform.Win and Winapi.Windows
- use the winapi GetWindowPlacement

---

```
procedure GetState
var 
  state : TWindowPlacement;
begin
  GetWindowPlacement( WindowHandleToPlatform(Application.MainForm.Handle).wnd, state);
end;
```

if state.showCmd have 2 mean that the Form is minimized,

the list of possible value of showCmd are here [ShowWindow function (winuser.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow)

There is no other property wrapped by Delphi where you can check the state.
in VCL Application there is not this issue, the form is resized while is minimized

**UPDATE:**
FMX simply, with the windows minimize message from OS does not update the variable Windows state, while it happens for VCL because is subscribed to **WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING** message and with this message call a function that update the window state.
In FMX the form is not directly subscribed to the windows message, the interface to the window is an object that implement an ""interface"" that have sone function useful for the window (like SetWindowState).

i found that writing the bound while minimized , will send automatically another set bound with the previous values immediately

Comment: Do you have permission to post the copyrighted code from Embarcadero? And that code is not relevant to your question anyway - the paragraph of text you wrote above it does not reference that quoted code or rely on it for information. You should remove it.

Comment: @KenWhite i'm sorry

Comment: @KenWhite, you're right that the 'code' was not really relevant, but I'm not so sure about the copyright issue.  Copyright law allows for quoting small portions of a copyright text (although I'm not sure how that might apply here), it was only function headers, not the actual code, and it was _public_ (and therefore documented) function headers in any case.

Comment: @PhilipJ.Rayment However I removed it to avoid any confusion . i wanted show only certain evidence. i forgot about the code that i use every day

Comment: @PhilipJ.Rayment: Why take the chance of posting copyrighted material when it's totally irrelevant? And IANAL, but I'm not posting anything that is copyrighted without permission, because those *cease and desist* letters that threaten lawsuits are no fun in your mailbox. The function headers in this case had absolutely nothing to do with the question being asked or any possible answer to it, so their presence was just unnecessary clutter anyway.

Comment: @KenWhite, as I said, "you're right that the 'code' was not really relevant,...".  I wasn't disputing that it could/should be removed.  (I believe that the minor relevance was to show that there wasn't a GetWindowsState method.)